# Java: why the array's length is 1 when nothing is in it

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am confused by the following code I wrote, as I thought the array's length (`allCommands`) would be 0 when nothing is in it.

The string `test` has only the pound sign in it, then I get the substring after it, which is followed by split with `#`.

```
String test = "#";
int beginIndex = test.indexOf("#");
test = test.substring(beginIndex+1);
String[] allCommands = test.split("#");
System.out.println("allCommands length: " + allCommands.length); // output: 1
System.out.println("allCommands array: " + Arrays.toString(allCommands)); // output: []
```

Can someone explain this? thanks!

Comment: There is something in it - it's a zero-length string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a zero length (empty) string, below program prints 0.

```
String test = "#";
int beginIndex = test.indexOf("#");
test = test.substring(beginIndex+1);
String[] allCommands = test.split("#");
System.out.println("allCommands length: " + allCommands.length); // output: 1
System.out.println(allCommands[0].length());
System.out.println("allCommands array: " + Arrays.toString(allCommands));
```

Comment: According to the Javadoc for `String.split`, "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array." So please explain why there's a trailing empty string in the array :)

Comment: thanks, but if I set `test = "#s1#s2#"`, what does the `allCommands[0].length()` mean then? it returns the length of the first string `s1`, which is not what I wanted to know. I wanted to know the length of `allCommands` array and the empty string should not be counted.

Comment: @TonyGW above example will split the string into two substrings `s1` and `s2`. So, `allCommands[0].length()` will be `2` (s1.length())

Comment: @DarshanMehta, yes I realized that, but that's not what I wanted to know, instead I wish to know the length of the array :( thanks!

Comment: @AndyTurner we are trying to split an empty `string` with some character. As that character is not present in that `String`, split returns the `string` as is. :)

Comment: @DarshanMehta which is not what the Javadoc describes.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) @AndyTurner it describes about trailing strings after the split. In our example, there is not split and hence, it's not stripped.

Answer (score 1):

Its an array of one empty string. Try running this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String[]{""}));
```

it will print `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use `test.split('#')` it returns an array of strings computed by the splitter which is the empty string in this case because there's nothing more to split. This empty string goes into your `String[] allCommands` so that's why the size is 1 and the array is empty.